# How to Force Selenium Webdriver to Use and Keep Cookies?

Tags: selenium, firefox, cookies, selenium-webdriver

I'm testing a website which uses cookies for security. Every time a user logs in with a different device or browser they must go through an intensive (email and phone keys) identity verification process. My backup/restore process uses a Firefox addon and works for manual testing.

However when I run Selenium I get triggered to go through the ID process every time. So either Selenium is not using the cookies, or is being given a different browser ID for some reason.

I set a breakpoint to check my cookies are loaded in the Selenium Firefox browser window, but my addon is not available in Selenium Firefox instances.

Selenium documentation is very slim on cookie use:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

So any info much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should use firefox profile which would be configured for verification? If you dont use profiles Selenium always runs 'blank' profile. Do you use Windows? What language do you use?

Comment: Yep, that works. Thanks! I was hoping for a flag in the Selenium Webdriver. Something like driver.enableCookies(); or similar. Anyway, this solution works great and allows for more than just cookie setting. Nice.

Comment: there are something like flag enableCookies, but still in firefox profile. First option to use profile is using Profile Manager. The second option is webdriver code, for example: `profile.setPreference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", 1);
`. You can change every preference available in `about:config` the same way

Comment: So there are flags to be set in Webdriver, but one must first get beyond the default blank profile. And the best/easiest way is using Profile Manager. Surprised I never stumbled on this earlier, just never had the need. Once again, great feedback- thanks :)

Comment: I said 'something like flag', but Firefox flag, not WebDriver function. For example if you'd like to configure Chrome you would use different approach. I'm glad to help you :)